# How to use $A.util.toggleClass with Lightning Design System

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

So I am looking at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_show_hide_markup.htm) page thinking that it is perfect for my use case.

However this example uses a custom CSS class but in my component I want to use the Lightning Design System. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you're asking if you can use that utility function to add and remove *any* CSS class name, including the ones from SLDS.

Yes.

Example which adds or removes the standard `slds-hide` class from a spinner element.

```
var spinner = component.find('spinner');
$A.util.toggleClass(spinner, 'slds-hide');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extract from the Salesforce documentation on this subject
entitled, "Adding and removing style in Lightning" at
[Adding and removing style in Lightning](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_styles.htm)

To append or remove CSS classes from a component or element, use the `$A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'class')` and `$A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'class')` methods.
The `$A.util.toggleClass(cmp, 'class')` method adds or removes the class depending on the current state.